# R: Reversing the fill order in a double bar graph

Tags: r

Hi I have a double bar graph. I have searched for it, but I can't quite get what I want. Example of searches.

[Reverse fill order of stacked bars with faceting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134596/reverse-fill-order-of-stacked-bars-with-faceting)

[R - ggplot2 reverse order of bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155985/r-ggplot2-reverse-order-of-bar)

[In ggplot2 for R, how do I reverse the order of the bar colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566697/in-ggplot2-for-r-how-do-i-reverse-the-order-of-the-bar-colors)

Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to post an image :(

Here is my code:

```
dat9 <- data.frame(
  Response = factor(c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No", "No", "No",  "No", "No")),
  Category = factor(c("Under 45","45-64","65+","Men","Women","Under 45", "45-64", "65+", "Men", "Women"), levels=c("Under 45","45-64","65+", "Men", "Women")),
  percentage = c(79, 69, 44, 65, 72, 16, 22, 39, 25, 20))

ggplot(data=dat9, aes(x=Category, y=percentage, fill=Response,)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")
```

(Not enough reputation to post PNG!)

I would like to reverse the red and blue bars in the image. Also reverse the blue and red box in the legend.

Updated (Added PNG)
[image]

Comment: By reversing, do you mean plotting the column "Yes" first followed by "No"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reorder the factor levels of Response. By default, factor levels follow an alphabetical order and ggplot2 respects this ordering.

```
dat9 <- data.frame(
    Response = factor(c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No", "No", "No",  "No", "No")),
    Category = factor(c("Under 45","45-64","65+","Men","Women","Under 45", "45-64", "65+", "Men", "Women"), levels=c("Under 45","45-64","65+", "Men", "Women")),
    percentage = c(79, 69, 44, 65, 72, 16, 22, 39, 25, 20))
dat9$Response <- factor(dat9$Response,levels=c("Yes","No"))
ggplot(data=dat9, aes(x=Category, y=percentage, fill=Response,)) +
         geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale_fill_manual to pick the order and colors of the bars.  This also addresses the diagonal lines through the legend key boxes.

```
ggplot(data=dat9, aes(x=Category, y=percentage, fill=Response,)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]